# Utilizing Jenkins to create branches and profiles in Clearcase

Tags: jenkins, groovy, branch, clearcase, jenkins-groovy

I am pretty new to configuration management and trying to come up with a more efficient way to create branches. One of my concepts is to utilize Jenkins to create the actual profiles and branches. How would I go about doing that, and is there a plug-in in Jenkins that can best assist in achieving that?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a plug-in in Jenkins that can best assist in achieving that?

Not that I know of.
The recommended approach remains to script your process:

- [`cleartool mkbrtype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbrtype.htm) / [`cleartool mkbranch`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbranch.htm)
- [`cleartool mkview`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm) (I don't believe there is cleartool commands for [View profile](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/about-view-profiles))

Once you have a script which does what you need (script in any scripting language you want), you can call it from your Jenkins Groovy pipeline.